# Is it safe to use a Wymeditor on a live site? Could an automated script disable javascript?

Tags: javascript, security, xss, wymeditor

Im curious, the pages in question are password protected but it got me thinking. Im experitmenting with the Wymeditor J-Query plugin, it works rather well and deals with XSS scripting attempts by automatically converting angle brackets into html characters etc.

Obviously with direct access a user could disable javascript and then insert any manner of malicious tags into the DB. However i am wondering would it be possible for an automated script to disable javascript if it managed to get buy the password protection, and thus insert malicious scripts to the DB which would then be run when DB information is displayed on another page??

*** UPDATE ***

I should probably have expanded a bit. I would usually strip_tags() and use prepared statements however for Wymeditor to be of any use to the client then I can't use strip_tags(). I know I could write some code to remove any malicious looking content but im not sure just how much malicious content i would be looking for, im assuming XSS attacks are alot more varied than just < script >do bad stuff< script > type of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rule #1: **never trust user data**.

Corollary: anything that comes from the client side *is* user data, no matter what in-browser measures your page takes (An automated script might not be running JS at all to begin with, or may inject form fields not present on your page).

So, while the JS editor doesn't make the site any *less* safe, it doesn't provide any *additional* security either: client-side measures (such as JS input filtering) are for user convenience *only* and provide exactly zero protection; **you *need* to sanitize user input server-side,** regardless of client-side.

Comment: I am aware of this hence why i am asking about Wymeditor, is it ever safe to use such a plugin on a live site? Obviously certain forums allow you to bold text etc without adding <b> tags so im wondering how they get around it. I should add that i always strip_tags() and use prepared statements when enetering info to a DB but in this case to use Wymeditor is requires some tags to be entered aswell.

Comment: Safety is **completely unrelated** to the plugin. It doesn't make the site any more or less safe; safety needs to be ensured at the server side.

Comment: … so if you want to allow some HTML, then you have to use a defence that allows it (which usually means a DOM parser and a whitelist of acceptable tags and attributes).

Comment: @cosmicsafari: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sanitize+user+input , perhaps also add the name of your server-side language?

Comment: @Piskvor I done a bit more research and came accross the htmlpurifier PHP library which does exactly what im looking for, well with a little bit of customisation.

Answer (score 1):

You should `check your data upon insert` into the database ... no client side script can protect you.  Wymeditor can make the input easier and can help a lot, it but will not protect you against malicious pieces of codes which some hackers will try to insert. So you have to do a stron server side check.

Comment: "Checking upon insert" is already too late - see "xss reflection attacks". You need to sanitize the inputs before your program starts accessing them in any way.

Comment: Yes normally the frst thing which is done serverside is to clean the posted data from suspicious pieces. May be I didn't explain it corectly.